# Is there a most suited filesystem for distributed game tree traversal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, mpi

I have been looking at [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=2A93D98BDCDDE9B3235EAE4BCA7D52FE?doi=10.1.1.499.9708&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on distributed game tree traversal and (with help from others) attempted to make a Python/mpi4py clone of the software tree traverser in order to solve 2-player abstract strategy games.

Firstly, [Wikipedia provides a breif description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree) on how to "solve" a game.

It is a common optimization to remember results that have already been solved so further tree traversal is un-needed. As a cluster of computers cannot trivially share the results amongst each other a variety of approaches have been taken to solve this issue. The method in the paper (Transposition Table Driven Work Scheduling) works essentially as follows:

1. Give an ID to each computer 1 to n (I just used the standard MPI rank)
2. At any particular point a computer may receive a position. Check to see if the position is in the look up table or trivially done. If it is, send back the resulting value, otherwise, generate the children.
3. Hash each child position so they have an associated value of 1 to n. Send each position to the "correct" computer with the ID of the hash.
4. Repeat until the initial position has been solved.

As the paper even mentions, this method works somewhat paradoxically, having an incredibly high communication rate.

Here are the issues:

On a single computer it seems to work fine. I then ran some tests on my school's cluster and ran into some serious issues. Solving a game like TicTacToe was abysmal often timing out in "debug mode" (4 nodes, 20 cores, and 15 minute time limit).

I saved the TicTacToe solution database to what they call the "user directory" (more can be [found here](http://research-it.berkeley.edu/services/high-performance-computing/user-guide/savio-user-guide)). This is in contrast to the "scratch" directory which is normally used to store data. When I did this, the database for TicTacToe was solved in a matter of seconds.

I noticed that the "scratch" space used ["Lustre FS"](http://lustre.org/) which appears to be a poor choice for "peer-to-peer" applications:

> While a Lustre file system can function in many work environments, it
>   is not necessarily the best choice for all applications. It is best
>   suited for uses that exceed the capacity that a single server can
>   provide, though in some use cases, a Lustre file system can perform
>   better with a single server than other file systems due to its strong
>   locking and data coherency.
>
> A Lustre file system is currently not particularly well suited for
>   "peer-to-peer" usage models where clients and servers are running on
>   the same node, each sharing a small amount of storage, due to the lack
>   of data replication at the Lustre software level. In such uses, if one
>   client/server fails, then the data stored on that node will not be
>   accessible until the node is restarted.

I might just not have a solid enough grasp of distributed computing, but it seems that Lustre FS might not objectively be good fit for this kind of problem. Unfortunately, the cluster I was using is locked in to using Lustre FS. Another option is something like Google Cloud Engine or AWS to do the task, however I am confused about some points:

1. A lot of the abstractions seem to scare me. All of these cloud platforms offer "scalable solutions" which often involve "load balancing" which is not only unnecessary, but detrimental to the algorithm. (It is imperative the positions are sent to the correct computers so they can be looked up quickly). Does Google Cloud Engine or AWS provide away of getting bare bones enough for this algorithm to work effectively?
2. What filesystem should I be using? Google Cloud Engine recomends NFS or Gluster, but I am unsure. The paper is fairly outdated and doesn't seem to use anything special. Does AWS or Google Cloud Engine offer an appropriate filesystem for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0):

Without any code nor a description of how the filesystem is used, it is really hard to provide some valuable help.
Anyway, if i read between the line

- you build a "database" of solutions
- this "database" is implemented on top of a filesystem
- adding an entry is a file creation
- a lookup is a file existence check

did i get it right ?

if yes, then this is not a surprise performance is awful and do not scale.
you are basically asking a parallel filesystem what it does worst : a lot of metadata access from all nodes, which involve under the hood traffic to keep a consistent view of the filesystem.

how much data do you need to store the solutions ?

at first glance, it might be faster to store them in an old school database (such as MySQL).

an other option would be to store this on a local filesystem, and have the remote nodes issue queries to the task running where the data is stored (create this file, does this file exist) so there is no need to keep meta-data consistent accross nodes.

a better version would be to have all the nodes store solutions and replies to queries. you could hash a solution and deduce on which node it is stored, so you know which MPI tasks should be asked to store the solution or issue a query.

if you really have to use a filesystem, then NFS might be a better choice than a parallel filesystem such as lustre, glusterfs or gpfs.